# Angular style not applied to component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-components

The following code renders the horizontal scrollbar as expected in the browser:

my-component.html

```
<!-- Test Modal -->
<div class="modal fade modalsize" data-backdrop="false" id="testModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Test</h4>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Company</th><th>Company</th><th>Company</th><th>Company</th><th>Company</th><th>Company</th><th>Company</th>
            <th>Company</th><th>Company</th><th>Company</th><th>Company</th><th>Company</th><th>Company</th><th>Company</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my-component.css

```
#wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

[image]

However, when I try to use another component inside the modal, the styles aren't applied / scrollbar doesn't render:

my-component.html

```
<div class="modal fade modalsize" data-backdrop="false" id="testModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <my-second-component (valueSelected)='selectValue($event)'></my-second-component>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my-second-component.html

```
<div id="mywrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Component</th><th>Component</th><th>Component</th><th>Component</th><th>Component</th><th>Component</th><th>Component</th>
      <th>Component</th><th>Component</th><th>Component</th><th>Component</th><th>Component</th><th>Component</th><th>Component</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

my-second-component.css

```
#mywrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

[image]

**Update**
@Mohamed.Karkotly figured it out - my-second-component.ts was missing the style URL for the component css:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-second-component',
  templateUrl: './my-second-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-second-component.component.css'] <-- This was missing
})
```

Comment: This is weird, use `::ng-deep` before your `#mywrapper` CSS rule as a temporal fix until you figure it out.

Comment: Did you make sure that in your `my-second-component.ts` you've got `styleUrls: ['./my-second-component.css']` within your `@Component` decorator?

Comment: can you set 100% width for :host in second-component css? normally html table takes width from parent.

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly You were right, I was missing the style URL  Thanks, feel free to post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that might face this problem in the future, this might be due to a missing `styleUrls` array within `@Component` decorator of the component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-second-component',
  templateUrl: './my-second-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-second-component.component.css'] <-- This was missing
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make use of the View Encapsulation options too.

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom // <-- ShadowDom , None or Emulated
})
class MyApp {
}
```